# When is it necessary to use "of"?

Tags: prepositions

For instance

> Curvature radius

and

> Radius of curvature

Is there difference between both? When I need to use "of" in this kind of word?

Another example

> Computing time

and

> Time of computing

Are they the same? I already saw the both, in academic books, and I'm confused with it. In my language always it is used "of".

Thank you in advance.

Comment: In the first example, I think the emphasis is different, and the use is contextual ('the radius of the curvature instead of its direction'). In the second example the meaning is actually different: the first indicates the time it takes to compute, whereas the other (possibly) signifies the time the computing was performed.

Comment: What do you mean by "time of computing" and "computing time": is this referring to a historical period, a point in time when you can start computing, or the elapsed time a computing operation takes? In any case, if you have questions about learning English, you should post on ell.stackexchange.com, not here.

Comment: @StuartF, I mean elapsed time.